# AWS Sagemaker - ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateTransformJob operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to run a batch transform job on AWS sagemaker. However, I keep getting the following error when I create a transformer and run the transform method:

```
ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateTransformJob operation: Could not find model "arn:aws:sagemaker:eu-west-1:775938635291:model/tensorflow-yolov3-2019-01-31-15-41-17-966".
```

This is the part of my code where I run the transform method:

```
# Initialize the transformer object
transformer = sagemaker.transformer.Transformer(
    base_transform_job_name='Batch-Transform',
    model_name="tensorflow-xxxxx-xxxx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx",
    instance_count=1,
    instance_type='ml.c4.xlarge',
    output_path=output_location,
    accept='application/json', 
    sagemaker_session=sage.Session(),
    max_payload = 100,
    max_concurrent_transforms = 5
    )

# To start a transform job:
transformer.transform(input_location, content_type='application/json')
# Then wait until transform job is completed
transformer.wait()
```

Anybody that can explain why I could get the error above?

Comment: Did you create a model using the CreateModel API call (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/API_CreateModel.html )?

Answer (score 2):

Error say it can't find the model you reference. Find it using this command line command:

```
aws sagemaker list-models
```

Note: make sure the job, model and listing is in the same eu-west-1 region.